# Counting the number of loops when using the 'While' function

Tags: r, while-loop

I would like to calculate the number of times the function repeats before it exceeds the condition. For example;

```
y=0
while(y<10) {
  y=y+2
  print(y)
}

[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 10
```

Obviously, the function repeats 5 times, but how can I show this in R?

Answer (score 8):

You almost had it.

```
y <- i <- 0
while(y < 10) {
  i <- i + 1
  y <- y + 2
  print(y)
}
print(sprintf("The loop repeated %s times.", i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using recursion.
For example you want to set limit to five times execution.

```
       function test(int y,int current,int limit){ 
      if (current>limit) return;
      print (y);
      test(y+2,current+1,limit); 

}
```

calling the function within your main code:

```
    int start=0;
     test(start,1,5);
```

Comment: Cool, tho' of course the whole point of `while` is to avoid filling a loop or a function with `if` statements :-) .  Recursion is typically used when the terminal value is unknown or the function itself changes (see any sample "factorial" recursion function).